# Is there any method to automatically run a script every 30 mins using selenium with Python?

Tags: python, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automation

I'm working on automation testing with Selenium using Python and I'm new to testing. Are there any ways to automate a script to run every 30 minutes?

Comment: Are you on linux system? If on linux,  youcan simply use cron to do the job.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily use an Event Thread in python to execute a task/function after regular intervals.

```
import threading

def hello():
    print('Hello World')

WAIT_MINUTES = 30
WAIT_TIME = WAIT_MINUTES * 60

ticket = threading.Event()

while not ticker.wait(WAIT_TIME ):
    hello()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using windows machine you can use windows task scheduler to schedule your Python script

[WIndows Task Scheduler](https://towardsdatascience.com/automate-your-python-scripts-with-task-scheduler-661d0a40b279)

if you are uing linux you can use cron jobs to schedule your python script

[Cron jobs](https://medium.com/better-programming/https-medium-com-ratik96-scheduling-jobs-with-crontab-on-macos-add5a8b26c30)

Answer (score 0):

You can use cron jobs. [here](https://pypi.org/project/python-crontab/) you can find a python module to use.

as for general usage you can do the following:

```
from crontab import CronTab
cron = CronTab(user='root')
job = cron.new(command='run selenium tests')
job.minute.every(30)
cron.write()
```